# pygame.event.get() is not returning any event

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

...
...

while True:
   #comment
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == KEYDOWN:
         key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
         #do something
```

I replaced `#comment` with a print statement and found that the `for loop`  is not at all executed i.e, print statement is running infinitely.

What I'm expecting is that, `get_pressed()` returns the key pressed as soon as the key is pressed, but it's not happening.

What's wrong in the above code and how do I correct it?

EDIT: Adding link to python script file
[python script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByP5h3h0_JHNLTA5OXNOS19sQXM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.event.get()` grabs all of the events that have registered in the event queue and keeps them in the order they happened. `pygame.key.get_pressed()` only has the keys that are pressed in that moment. That means that they have to be pressed when your game tries to access them.

You don't need to use both of these methods together. Instead just loop through the events and do something when a key matches one that you want. A common thing is to react to the cursor keys which is shown below:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
...
...

while True:
    #comment
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                print('Down was pressed')

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print('Up was pressed')

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print('Right was pressed')

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print('Left was pressed')
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned. I opened the terminal and ran the command `$python control.py` but when I press the key_up button(with the window focus on terminal), I get the following output
`^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[` and it doesn't look like the execution is going into the for loop. Am I doing wrong in the way I'm launching the python code? or what's going wrong?

Comment: Python is launching fine, but you shouldn't be interacting with pygame through the console. It should open a GUI window where you see the game. Did you call `pygame.init` before starting your game loop? I'll edit my answer to make it more complete.

Comment: yes, I have called `pygame.init()` method, but no GUI window popped up. Is there anything I'm missing? I have edited the question by adding link to the python script

Comment: Oh thanks a lot!...`pygame.init()` did not create a GUI window to interact with pygame, I had to create it manually using `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))`, and now everything seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Please mark this answer as correct if it answered your original question.